# WPF DataBinding to a Property from an object

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm, data-binding

I bound a property from an object to a control but the property won't update...

I triedit in this way:

ViewModelBase:

```
public class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    [NotifyPropertyChangedInvocator]
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
    {
        PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class VIewModel : ViewModelBase
{
    private Person _person;

    public Person Person
    {
        get { return _person; }
        set
        {
            _person = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Person));
        }
    }
}
```

Personclass:

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

}
```

App.xamls.cs

```
protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
{
    var viewModel = new VIewModel
    {
        Person = new Person{FirstName = "Dominik", Name = "Muster"}
    };

    var window = new MainWindow {DataContext = viewModel};
    window.Show();
    base.OnStartup(e);
}
```

MainWindow:

```
<StackPanel>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Person.Name}"/>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Person.FirstName}" Width="200"/>
</StackPanel>
```

When the program is started, the value of the textboxes are the value of the contact-object, but if I change the text-value in the textbox, the property will not be updated... any ideas?

Comment: Tried to implement the INotifyPropertyChanged in the class Person?

Comment: You have to inform the viewmodel of when you want the properties updated, so in your Binding add the UpdateSourceTrigger and set it to PropertyChanged and your properties will reflect the value in the textboxes: Text="{Binding Person.Name, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}

Comment: @Sabrina_cs your solution doesn't work...

Comment: @cicciorocca thx for your solution! it works!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try Implement INotifyPropertyChanged In the class Person:

```
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private string _name;
    private string _firstName;

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _name;
        }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Name");
        }
    }


public string FirstName
{
    get
    {
        return _firstName;
    }
    set
    {
        _firstName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
    }
}

protected void OnPropertyChanged(string name)
{
    PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(name));
}
```

}